# iPhone OS 3.0 playing movies wont work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

The following code used to work but now it doesn't and I have not changed anything about it.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:)]) {
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedLink]]; 
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
        [moviePlayer release];
    }
    else {
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedLink]] autorelease];
        [moviePlayer play];
    }
```

So if the OS supports the method presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated we use this approach but if its OS < 3.2 we use the old method but this doesn't work anymore on my iPhone 1st gen OS 3.0.1 or iPod Touch 2nd gen OS 3.1.3. Nothing happens when the code is fired.

Hope you can help me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh its the autorelease part which is doing the wreckage.

From

```
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedLink]] autorelease];
    [moviePlayer play];
```

to

```
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedLink]];
    [moviePlayer play];
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shall set the MPMoviePlayerController view frame to the CGRect you want to display it and then add this view as a subview before playing. Have a look [at Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html)

Comment: Nope that does not work on 3.0+, the MPMoviePlayerController does not have a view.